# pass form as an argument to graphics c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with graphics in windows forms. I need to pass the form itself (named `form1`) which is calling the graphics class `Grafika()` so that while drawing I can use `form1.CreateGraphics()` to draw on that specific form.

The constructor for the graphics class `Grafika` looks like this:

```
public Grafika(ref Form predan)
{
    grafika=predan.CreateGraphics();
    //drawing on the form
}
```

How to pass a form into the constructor of `Grafika` so that I can use it?

Comment: Do not try to cache a Graphics object!

Comment: Code that calls `CreateGraphics` is 99.9% likely to be wrong. I see no reason to think this is an exception. All drawing should be done in response to `Paint` event, which gives you a `Graphics` object to use.

Comment: It does make sense to pass out the e.Graphics object to methods or classes that do the actual drawing but neither storing it there (where it will soon get invalid) let alone creating a transient new one there is likely to work properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass it along don't use `ref`. If you remove the ref you can pass it like so:

```
//From Form1
Grafika g = new Grafika(this);
//If called from the From, 'this' will be the form itself
```

Also your constructor should look like this:

```
public Grafika(Form1 predan)//Notice Form1 instead of just Form
{
    grafika=predan.CreateGraphics();
    //drawing on the form
}
```

Comment: I did try that, but i got "keyword 'this' is not available in the current context", after more research i found out that i must call it from within a method of the form, not outside. TY for getting me on the right track.

Comment: Yes when creating the class on Form1. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The same way you have posted, have your constructor accepts a parameter of that specific form. But you don't need the `ref` keyword since `Form` is of reference type itself. Here `Form1` is a specific `Form` object considering you have a form of that name

```
public Grafika(Form1 predan)
{
    grafika=predan.CreateGraphics();
    //drawing on the form
}
```